# Как сделать расположение вкладок сверху?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Решил попробовать новую фичу Visual Studio 16.4- это расположение вкладок не сверху, а сбоку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что-то понять не могу, а как теперь вернуться назад...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все таки нашел опцию:

Environment-> Tabs and Windows ->Set tab Layout

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]